# Cargar datos de un base de datos al pulsar botones (siguiente y anterior) No retrocede

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Poseo un sistema que muestra "TIPS" de salud contenidos en una base de datos.
Quisiera agregar botones de **siguiente** y **anterior**

La idea es que al pulsar siguiente o anterior se cambie el nume_cons y luego se cargue el titulo, la descripcion y la imagen (**obtener.php**)

ACTUALMENTE EL PROBLEMA ES QUE: SOLO AUMENTA LOS VALORES AL PULSAR SIGUIENTE NO RETROCEDE A LOS ANTERIORES:

INDEX

```
  <?php
include "conexion.php";
include "funciones/obtener.php";

    //include "funciones/cargar.php";

    if (!isset($_REQUEST["nume_cons"])){
      $_REQUEST["nume_cons"] = 0;
    }else{
      if (!is_numeric($_REQUEST["nume_cons"])){
         $_REQUEST["nume_cons"] = 0; 
     }
    }
    $nume_cons = $_REQUEST["nume_cons"];
    if (!is_numeric($nume_cons)){ 
       $nume_cons = 0;
      $anterior=0;
    }else{
     $anterior = $nume_cons++;    
    echo "anterior";
     }
      $siguiente = $nume_cons--;   
    echo "siguiente";
     //-- obtenemos los datos

    $datos     =    obtenerRegistro($nume_cons);
    $titu_cons =    $datos["titu_cons"];
    $desc_cons =    $datos["desc_cons"];
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

<meta utfset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">

</head>

<title>TuSalud</title>

<body>

<h1> TuSalud... Un consejo a la vez </h1>

<table>
  <tr>
        <td colspan="5">    <input  type="text"     id="nume_cons"  name="nume_cons" value="<?php echo $nume_cons;?>"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
        <td colspan="5">    <input  type="text"     id="titu_cons"  name="titu_cons" value="<?php echo $titu_cons;?>"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>                                                                                         
        <td colspan="5">    <img src="<?php echo obtenerImag($nume_cons);?>"> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
        <td colspan="5">    <input  type="text"     id="desc_cons"  name="desc_cons" value="<?php echo $desc_cons;?>"></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>



  <td><input type="button"  onclick="location.href='index.php?nume_cons=<?=$anterior;?>'"  value="Anterior"></td>
  <td><input type="button"  onclick="location.href='index.php?nume_cons=<?=$siguiente;?>'"  value="Siguiente"></td>
  </tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Obtener datos:

```
 <?php
require_once "./conexion.php";

function obtenerRegistro($nume_cons){
    global $cone;
    $consejos= mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT titu_cons,desc_cons FROM CONSEJO WHERE nume_cons=$nume_cons");
    $registro= mysqli_fetch_array($consejos);
    return array("titu_cons" => $registro["titu_cons"], "desc_cons" => $registro["desc_cons"]);
}

function obtenerImag($nume_cons){
    global $cone;
    $imagen= mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT nume_imag FROM CONSEJO WHERE nume_cons=$nume_cons");
    $img= mysqli_fetch_array($imagen);
    $nume_imag=$img["nume_imag"];
    $ruta_imag="./recursos/imagenes/imagen".$nume_imag.".jpg";
    return $ruta_imag;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero dejame decirte que a modo personal, el codigo a mySQL esta muy ordenado pero a mi gusto es muy ineficiente porque se realizan muchas consultas cuando seguro se podrían resolver en una sola. En fin... Una posible solución a lo que necesitas...

Veo que index.php hay una variable $nume_cons que determina el consejo a mostrar.
Supongo que es una especie de ID.

INDEX.PHP

```
    include "conexion.php";
    include "funciones/obtener.php";
    //include "funciones/cargar.php";

    if (!isset($_REQUEST["nume_cons])){
      $_REQUEST["nume_cons"] = 0;
    }else{
      if (!is_numeric($_REQUEST["nume_cons"])){
         $_REQUEST["nume_cons"] = 0; 
     }
    }
    $nume_cons = $_REQUEST["nume_cons"];
    if (!is_numeric($nume_cons)){ 
       $nume_cons = 0;
       $anterior = 0;
    }else{
       $anterior = $nume_cons--;    
     }
    $siguiente = $nume_cons++;

     //-- obtenemos los datos
     $datos = obtenerRegistro($nume_cons);
     $titulo = $datos["titulo"];
     $descrip = $datos["descripcion"];
     $imagen = $datos["imagen"];
```

Ahora los botones del index.php

`<td><input type="button"  onclick="location.href='funciones/opciones.php?opcion=4&nume_cons=<?=$siguiente;?>'"  value="Siguiente"></td>`

Luego en el resto de las funciones

Veo que haces muchas peticiones a la base de datos cuando podría ser en una consulta. Tambien pides todos los campos del registro pero solo usas uno, en el siguiente ejemplo de funcion llamo solo los campos solicitados y los retorno en forma de array para trabajarlo mas comodo luego

```
function obtenerRegistro($nume_cons){
    global $cone;
    $consejos= mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT titu_cons,desc_cons,nume_imag FROM CONSEJO WHERE ID=$nume_cons");
    $registro= mysqli_fetch_array($consejos);
    return array("titulo" => $registro["titu_cons"], "descipcion" => $registro["desc_cons"], "imagen" => $registro["nume_imag "]);
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, queria hacer eso de la array pero no me funcionaba bien, me salian errores de array to string, lo copie como esta y me da error porque dice que no encuentra al $nume_cons.
Publicare el error

Comment: Como hago para mostrar los datos del array?

Comment: ya vi los datos del array jejeje, ahora faltaria las opciones de siguiente y anterior

Comment: Donde te indica el error? En el index o en la funcion obtenrRegistro? Fijate que imprime $nume_cons

Comment: creo que el problema esta en que: cuando le das click a las opciones de siguiente, anterior, descargar, el te captura el option te manda al opciones.php y luego regresa, creo que como la accion de buscar el siguiente o anterior id (nume_cons++ o nume_cons --) esta en el mismo php deberia cambiar el onclick o en su defecto pasar ese codigo de anterior y siguiente para otro, o que sugieres?

NOTA ACTUALICE EL CODIGO

Comment: Por un tema de comodidad no hice comprobacion de variables. Ahi hice algunas y fijate que en el $_REQUEST se me fue equivocado un $nume_cons cuando tendria que haber sido $_REQUEST["nume_cons"]

Comment: te falto una comilla, sigue igual el problema pero en la linea 17, y si sacamos ese valor de CARGAR();?

Comment: Lo corregi decia "num_cons" y es "nume_cons", el problema es que ahora no carga nada sale todo vacio menos el ID

Comment: Hace una cosa, en la funcion obtener registro, en la consulta a mysql pone un valor fjo. ej **"SELECT titu_cons,desc_cons FROM CONSEJO WHERE nume_cons=4"**. Solo para saber si el problema esta en el numero nume_cons o despues de ahi...

Comment: habia salido  jejeje coloque un valor fijo y funciona perfecto entonces el problema esta en la obtencion del nume cons

Comment: cuando le das anterior devuelve a nume_cons como 0 y al darle siguiente como - 1

Comment: Corregi el codigo, ahora suma uno hasta llegar a 2 de alli no pasa y se regresa hasta cero

Comment: Pense una cosa, si le pasamos un parametro a CARGAR() para que cambie el valor, pues es esta funciona la que muestra el nume_cons